# We just upgraded to VB2017 Community: Can I create a custom toolbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to simplify the toolbox for beginner programmers.  There are too many entries in any of the toolboxes for the few that they will be using

How can I create a custom toolbox that will contain Button, Textbox, listbox, picturebox, for starters.

I saw "Tools/ Choose Toolbox items" and saw that I could select tools from the list but did not seem to be able to proceed from there.

If nothing else, can I arrange these to be at the top of the list of a toolbox?

Comment: What kind of toolbox are you talking about?  Toolbox for controls used during devolopment is another thing. You should open the Toolbox window, then right click on it and choose Add Tab

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

Right Click on the Toolbox and choose `Add Tab`. After adding the tab give the item a name.

The do one of the following:

- Right click on the new item and choose add items. A dialog will show up and could take some time to build the list of components available. Once completed in the dialog, add the items you would like.
- *(Faster method)* Right on an existing item in another Tool Box and choose copy. After copying the item right click on your custom toolbox and choose paste.

I have created a Custom Toolbox in the following screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the second option worked but not the first. Still, I have the custom toolbox Thanks

Comment: As a followup idea, maybe it should ask me if I want to add it to my custom toolbox as I use a tool.  This would be cool

Comment: Not a problem. The first option takes a while to build the component cache. If you don't have controls in the toolbox it might be your only option. You can mark this answer as correct so others know how to perform this task.

Comment: Under the vote next to answer there is a gray checkbox. Check it to accept an answer and it will turn green.

Comment: I did not find that but I did hover on the grey check mark.  The tool tip suggested that it is the "Check as Answer" .  IT turned green when I did.  I presume that it is marked accordingly.....